# Simple Algebra (solving for an unknown)

Tags: algebraic-manipulation, algebra

I am trying to solve this equation for kss with mathematical but the system is failing and so I am hoping to get some pointers here.

```
EulSS= B * Css^(-G)*(1 - D + A* kss^(1-A)) == Css^(-G)
```

When I try `Solve[EulSS, kss, Reals]` it fails.
When I try `Reduce[{EulSS && Css > 0 && G > 0 && A > 0 && A < 1 && B > 0 && B < 1 && G > 0}, kss, Reals]`it just goes into a constant loop.

I will appreciate the help.

Comment: I'm guessing it is too difficult for `Reduce` to sort out solutions in real space subject to the parameter constraints. You might instead solve with no restrictions. `In[36]:= EulSS = B*Css^(-G)*(1 - D + A*kss^(1 - A)) == Css^(-G);
Solve[EulSS, kss]

During evaluation of In[36]:= Solve::ifun: Inverse functions are being used by Solve, so some solutions may not be found; use Reduce for complete solution information.

Out[37]= {{kss -> (-((Css^G (-Css^-G + B Css^-G - B Css^-G D))/(
     A B)))^(1/(1 - A))}}`

Comment: First:  divide both sides by Css^(-G).  Then, replace the derivative operator D with d.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the proposal. I initially figured that mathematical would be able to work out the division from the information I provided.

Answer (score 1):

1. Divide both sides by Css^(-G)
2. Replace the derivative operator D by variable d
3. Replace upper-case letters (which conflict with Mathematica's internal names) with lower-case symbols
4. Ensure $0 < a < 1$

Then

```
Assuming[0<a<1,
Solve[k^(1 - a) == (1/b - 1 + d)/a, k,Reals]]
```

$$k = a^{\frac{1}{a-1}} \left(\frac{b}{b d-b+1}\right)^{\frac{1}{a-1}}$$

with constraints.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the proposal. I initially figured that mathematical would be able to work out the division from the information I provided.

Comment: But your `D` was as inappropriate as an isolated `Sin` or `Factor` or ...

Comment: I reworded it with the A, B and so for. I was using greek letters in mathematica and couldn't copy and paste that here. 
But again, thanks a lot for the suggestion and clarifications.